# How to match a file name by specifying a prefix substring?

Tags: bash, shell-script, filenames, wildcards, bash-expansion

I would like to copy the files, located on a remote machine, whose filenames match a prefix string, on my local machine.

I have tried to select only the files whose names start with either `massif` or `calgrind` using the following command:

```
scp my-machine:/home/user/a-folder/[massif,callgrind]* .
```

However, this expression allows to match the empty string plus any number of characters and therefore, matches all the filenames related to the directory.

What do I have to change to make it work correctly?

Comment: It seems that by using *square brackets* I was accepting any of the characters inside the square brackets and not the empty string as I first thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want curly-brackets there:

```
scp my-machine:/home/user/a-folder/{massif,callgrind}* .
```

Otherwise you're matching on single characters, rather than the two complete strings.

`bash` does a number of different types of expansion & substitution; these are documented in the bash man page - looks for the `EXPANSION` section. Here, the `[` type is covered under "Pathname Expansion" (it matches on pathnames) and `{` under "Brace Expansion" (it generates multiple arguments from the options provided, regardless of files present).

Comment: Aha! That is it. In fact it was accepting anything that would start with these letters plus the comma. Thank you!

Comment: Also, do you happen to know how you call this construct/feature? It was hard to find this information in google. I always hit the if [[...]]  or if[...] question from there.

Comment: I've just added an edit with some references to documentation, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The files may be selected using two methods: the patterns may be specified consecutively or successively.

### First method

This method requires to use a [Bash extended pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) to specify several patterns together. The user must enable the `extglob` shell option using the `shopt` builtin (c.f. [`shopt` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#index-shopt)) because the Bash extended patterns are not enabled by default.

```
prompt% scp username@hostname:"/home/user/dirname/@(foo|bar)*" .
```

The Bash sub-pattern `@(PATTERN-LIST)` allows to specify a list of one or more patterns separated by `|`. It matches one of the given patterns. For example, `@(foo|bar)` matches `foo` or `bar` but does not match `foobar`, `barfoo`, `foofoo`, `barbar`.

The glob star matches any string of characters, including the empty string. Therefore, the pattern `@(foo|bar)*` matches all filenames that start with `foo` or `bar` (prefix (sub)string).

This method works when the remote shell is Bash and its `extglob` shell option is enabled. The user may enable this Bash option in its configuration file (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`), on the remote machine.

### Second method

This method executes the same command with different arguments, several times. It works using a POSIX compliant shell.

```
for prefix in foo bar
do
    scp username@hostname:"/home/user/dirname/${prefix}*" .
done
```

### Brace expansion

This method is not robust because the resulting expression may specify filenames that do not exist.